# How can I call a jQuery function AFTER a form is submitted?

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

How do I call a jQuery function AFTER a form is submitted?

I know how to call a function ON submit, but I want to call it after the post is submitted and details are put into the database with PHP.

I'm making a website where the user can put items into a cart. This works fine. However, AFTER a product is posted and added into the cart I want to display a popup-box displaying the cart. Hence I need the function to be called AFTER the submit has completed.

Comment: You use ajax for submit post?

Comment: Agreed you'll need to use ajax so that the page is not destroyed and recreated by the postback action (caused by submitting the form). That way, you can continue to run scripts on the page (because ajax sends the data to the server asynchronously in the background, instead of doing a full postback)

Comment: Without ajax: change your `<form>` `action=` which determines where your page posts to and, relevant here, which page is returned (by that action).  Then your form-post-result opens in a new page and you know it's a new page because it's a *different* new page (or just has different parameters).   Having said that, if your use-case is to add to a cart, then you *probably* want ajax anyway (even without post-processing).

Comment: This may be XY question, but to answer your exact question: You can save cookies on the server when you submit. The cookie can have a timestamp and on init (loading the next page) you check cookies in JavaScript onload and check the timestamp.

Comment: @jcubic cookies are stored in the browser, not the server. Perhaps you were thinking of the Session

Comment: @ADyson Session uses Cookies and Server is saving cookies when sending request to browser, it doesn't matter that the browser is actually saving them since browser send them with every reqest. You save the timestamp on the server you don't need any sessions for this. Cookies are the way to save data between two requests and you can create cookie after the submit on the server.

Comment: @jcubic `Session uses Cookies`...sort of. Session uses _one_ cookie, to maintain the link between the server-side Session and the browser session. But the actual session data is stored on the server. Whereas if you put the data directly into a cookie, that data is stored in the browser. `it doesn't matter that the browser is actually saving them`...that depends on the nature of the data being stored, that could have security and/or reliability implications. In this case, maybe it's not important. But your wording was wrong - you implied that cookie data is stored on the server when it isn't.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry It may be a typo I mean saving by the server not on the server. The server is saving the cookies in the header of the HTTP response. Is that ok for you now? I don't understand what's the point of this conversation.

Comment: @jcubic because if you give people the wrong impression about how a technology works, it could have security and/or reliability implications, as I said above. That's the point. In programming,  every detail is important.

Comment: @ADyson I just assume that everybody knows how cookies work. And in PHP you have the function set_cookies() so you save cookies on the server. You can't save cookies in Browser because the browser is doing that. I still think that I was correct and you just arguing for no reason.

Comment: @jcubic It's a nice assumption but unfortunately, in my experience, newer programmers tend not to understand the detail (usually because, as yet, they haven't needed to).

Comment: @jcubic `in PHP you have the function set_cookies() so you save cookies on the server`...no, that's not what that function does. [Read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). _"setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers"_. It sends the cookie info in the HTTP response, so that the browser can save it when it receives the header. The cookie itself is not stored anywhere on the server. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie, and anywhere else you care to read about the details of cookie implementation.

Comment: @ADyson Again PHP is server side so you save the cookie on the server side, it's added to HTTP response but this happens on the server for god sake. You don't call PHP in the browser.

Comment: @ADyson will you fill better if I use "set cookie on the server", this is exactly the same because you don't have control over saving cookies by the browser.

Comment: @jcubic `this happens on the server`...yes, but it's not **saved** on the server, which is what you were saying. This is significant, because server-side data is much safer from a security point of view. I have seen plenty of questions here where people have put sensitive data into cookies, apparently not realising that it will be exposed on the client-side. That's why it's important. We shouldn't leave information here, on this public, searchable site, which might lead people to a misunderstanding of what it is safe to do in their application. I realise it wasn't your intention to mislead btw

Comment: @jcubic P.S. I have explained the situation clearly in my original comment. If I may say so, you're the one who is persistently arguing, despite being corrected multiple times. So if want to stop this discussion, you are very welcome to do so. But if you continue to state that black is white, I will continue to post corrections :-). Anyway... `set cookie on the server`...is OK-ish, but `set cookie using server-side code` would be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

> Hence I need the function to be called AFTER the submit has completed.

You can do that from `done()`, for example, assuming your form and Ajax request are like this:

```
<form id="target" action="#">
  <input type="text" id="id" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>



$( "#target" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var theId = $("input[name='id']",this).val();   
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { id : theId },
      dataType: "json"
    });
     
    request.done(function( serverData ) {
      showCart(serverData);
    });
     
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
});


//....

function showCart(dataForCart) {
    //Use dataForCart if needed and show cart
}
```

Since Ajax requests are asynchronous by default and should be, `showCart()` will be called when the Ajax request has succeeded.

For more details, check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).